# Creating business object with list from different tables using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have implemented the following data schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Characters]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [Name] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Attributes]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [Name] NVARCHAR(50) NULL, 
    [DataType] NVARCHAR(50) NULL,  
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AttributeValues]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [CharacterId] INT NOT NULL, 
    [AttributeId] INT NOT NULL, 
    [Text] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL, 
    [Number] DECIMAL NULL, 
    [Flag] BIT NULL, 
    [Date] DATETIME NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_AttributeValuesCharacter] FOREIGN KEY (ChracterId) REFERENCES Characters(Id), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_AttributeValuesAttribute] FOREIGN KEY (AttributeId) REFERENCES Attributes(Id)
)
```

Table `Characters` saves characters and table `Attributes` saves attributes for those characters. Using the table `AttributeValues`, attributes can be assigned to a character with a value of any type. For my current situation, every character has an entry together with every attribute from the table 'Attributes' and a specific value of course. The value stands in the column of its type then.
I have chosen this design because I need a very flexible data schema, which enables me to add new `Attributes` of any type for a `Character`.

I am new to Entity Framework and C# and I need to build something like the following business object:

```
public class CharacterExtended
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Dictionary<string, DynamicValue<T> attributes {get; set; }
    }
```

So I need a character business object with all of its attribute names and values from the shown tables. Which would be best practice realizing this scenario using Entity Framework? Maybe someeone can give me an approach.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework can't map a tables to Dictionary and from my point of view is not the best approach.

Just use something like this:

```
    public class AttributeValue
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }

        public virtual int CharacterId { get; set; }

        public virtual int AttributeId { get; set; }

        public virtual string Text { get; set; }

        public virtual decimal? Number { get; set; }

        public virtual bool? Flag { get; set; }

        public virtual DateTime? Date { get; set; }

        public virtual Attribute Attribute { get; set; }

        public virtual Character Character { get; set; }

        public dynamic GetValue() 
        {
            switch (Attribute.DataType)
            {
                case Attribute.ValueTypes.Text:
                    return Text;
                case Attribute.ValueTypes.DateTime:
                    return Date ?? DateTime.MinValue;
                case Attribute.ValueTypes.Decimal:
                    return Number ?? 0M;
                case Attribute.ValueTypes.Boolean:
                    return Flag ?? false;
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        public T? GetValue<T>() where T : struct
        {
            switch (typeof(T).Name)
            {
                case "String":
                    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(Text, typeof(T));
                case "Decimal":
                    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(Number ?? 0M, typeof(T));
                case "Boolean":
                    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(Flag ?? false, typeof(T));
                case "DateTime":
                    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(Date ?? DateTime.MinValue, typeof(T));
            }

            throw  new InvalidOperationException();
        }

    }
```

And you can use it like this:

```
 var dob = attributes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Attribute.Name == "date_of_birth"); 
 if (dob == null)
 {
     dob.GetValue(); // dynamic
     dob.GetValue<DateTime>(); // type variable
 }
```